# $E[X(X-1)]$ of a Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X~\sim B(n,p)$ be a binomial random variable.
Calculate $E[X(X-1)]$.

Do I need to use the Binomial theorem?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E[X(X-1)]$$
$$=\sum_{x=0}^nx(x-1){n\choose x}p^xq^{n-x}$$
$$=\sum_{x=2}^nx(x-1)\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^xq^{n-x}$$
$$=n(n-1)p^2\sum_{x=2}^n\frac{(n-2)!}{(x-2)!(n-x)!}p^{x-2}q^{n-x}$$
$$=n(n-1)p^2(p+q)^{n-2}$$
$$=n(n-1)p^2$$
Note that $x(x-1)=0$ for both $x=0$ and $x=1$, so the range of summation an be taken as $x=2,3,\dots,n$; after factoring $n(n-1)p^2$ through the summation, the remaining sum is just $(p+q)^{n-2}$ from the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thank you. Now what is $X$'s variance?

Comment: The variance is $E[X(X-1)]+\mu_X-\mu_X^2=E[X(X-1)]-\mu_X(\mu_X-1)$.  Thus it is $n(n-1)p^2-np(np-1)=np(1-p)=npq$.

Comment: I'm using $\sigma_X^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.  Where $\mu_X=E[X]$.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: It is $E(X(X-1))=E(X^2)-E(X)$.

And $Var(X)=E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2  \Rightarrow E(X^2)=Var(X)+[E(X)]^2$

Comment: I don't understand why $E(X(X-1))=E(X^2)-E(X)$. Could you help me see it?

Comment: @UdiBehar It's true in general that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$.  That's true even if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: @UdiBehar $E(X(X-1))=E(X^2-X)=E(X^2)-E(X)$